# Gitlab-CI for Python project with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci

I want to set Gitlab-CI for my python project with SonarQube. I have one problem with that.
I set SonarQube variables in settings gitlab-ci.

This is my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:

    SONARQUBE_ARGUMENTS_NORMAL: -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN -Dsonar.password=$SONAR_PASSWORD --stacktrace
    SONARQUBE_ARGUMENTS_PREVIEW: -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN -Dsonar.password=$SONAR_PASSWORD --stacktrace -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_PATH -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    STAGE_ID: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}_${CI_JOB_NAME}_${CI_JOB_ID}

image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - python --version
  - python -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))'
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install --upgrade setuptools
  - pip install pytest
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

stages:
  - Static Analysis
  - Test

mypy:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
  - python -m pip install mypy
  - pwd
  - ls -l
  - python -m mypy --ignore-missing-imports *.py

flake8:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
  - python -m pip install flake8
  - flake8 --max-line-length=120 /*.py

pylint:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
  - pip install pylint
  - pylint -d C0301,C0114 *.py

test:
  stage: Test
  script:
  - pwd
  - ls -l
  - export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:."
  - python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
  - pytest sonarqube $SONARQUBE_ARGUMENTS_NORMAL

after_script:
  - echo "End CI"
```

Static analisys (flake8, mypy, pylint) works fine but I have problem with test stage where I use Pytest.
In CI log I have that:

```
 $ pytest sonarqube $SONARQUBE_ARGUMENTS_NORMAL
 ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
 pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: -Dsonar.host.url=http://127.0.0.0:8000 -Dsonar.login=my_login -Dsonar.password=my_password --stacktrace
```

Can you give me any idea, what I doing wrong?
I doing that same in android project with gradle and that works fine.

```
./gradlew test sonarqube $SONARQUBE_ARGUMENTS_NORMAL
```

Comment: `pytest` and `gradlew` are two different tools. You can't just pass the same command line arguments of one tool to another and expect it to just work. I suspect you want to run the tests with `pytest` and publish the results to sonarqube? Maybe [this passage from the sonarqube docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=4784145#content/view/4784145) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the sonar-scanner package on your runner and call directly to sonar-scanner binary with the needed properties on a sonar.properties file